# Automation testing technique to test maps

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, mapbox

Can anyone me suggest me automated testing approach to test maps, coordinates, assets plotted on maps.

I am trying to build automated testing framework using selenium to test maps, coordinates, location etc.  If anyone has tried anything like this before, please give suggestion for better approach.

Comment: It would be much easier to get an answer, if you provide more details. Like technologies used.

Comment: Technologies used for map development is : mapbox and coding language : C# and for testing I am going to use Java & Selenium webdriver